# Cocos2d-Android - What is the difference between Sprite.getcontentsize , Sprite.getscale , Sprite.gettexture

Tags: android, size, sprite, cocos2d-android

The Title says it all. I want to know what is the difference between Sprite.getcontentsize, Sprite.gettexture , Sprite.getscale. and How are they used.
I couldn't find any resources following this question.

Comment: Hoping my explanation may help you in  understanding it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for example image with name "test.png" with width 100px and height 200px. Then:

```
CCSprite testImage = CCSprite.sprite("test.png");

// print original image size
System.out.println("" + testImage.getContentSize().width + ", " + testImage.getContentSize().height); // print: 100, 200

// print actual image size
System.out.println("" + testImage.getBoundingBox().size.width + ", " + testImage.getBoundingBox().size.height); // print: 100, 200

// this will change resolution of image to half, so it will be drawn 2x smaller then original size
testImage.setScale(0.5f); 

// print how many is image scaled
System.out.println("" + testImage.getScale()); // print: O.5

// print original image size
System.out.println("" + testImage.getContentSize().width + ", " + testImage.getContentSize().height); // print: 100, 200
// print actual image size
System.out.println("" + testImage.getBoundingBox().size.width + ", " + testImage.getBoundingBox().size.height); // print: 50, 100
```

`testImage.gettexture()`will probably return loaded texture/image, but I don't know, I have never needed to use this function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as per my knowledge:

1. `Sprite.getContentSize()` --> It will return the size of Sprite(i.e its width and height)
2. `Sprite.getScale()` --> It will return the amount the resolution it shrinked (By default its value is 1.This method  is used if you want to change its size at runtime)

   If it is >1 then the sprite size will be more and <1 will give smaller size

*Note: `Sprite.getContentSize()` has no effect on the scaled sprite. It will give original sprite size only though it scaled above or below to normal.*

3. `Sprite.getTexture()` --> It will give image of that sprite.It is used if you want to crate another sprite with same texture (image) i.e.

   ```
   CCSprite newSprite = CCSprite.sprite(Sprite.getTexture());
   ```